# How to create and reuse particular screen/view in Storyboard in different places depending on context?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have to create an application with similar view controllers in different places depending on context.

For example "add/edit address" viewcontroler should be available in my profile and then in place order flow.

Or for example, "add/edit" credit card viewcontroler should be available during signing up, in my profile and as well in place order flow.

I understand that I can create equal viewcontrollers and place them in story board in all such places. I guess it's not a good approach.

But I don't know how to create an object with viewcontroller (code and ui part) that would be stand-alone/independent and reusable in different places. Can get the point how to use such entity depending on user context.

Thank you

> added comment below:

Ok, so I have create and application with many views, many flows (like home screen, my profile, sign up flow, order flow, etc).

I understand that for each state/view I can create a view controller in storyboard. But I see in advance that there are some screens/views that are repeated and actually are the same. So I guess I can decrease their number, create repeated views just ones and reuse them in different storyboard part.

For example. There is a separate screen/view "Add credit card" in 3 different places in story board:

- during sign up flow
- in my profile (like in my account)
- during place order flow

I know how to create mentioned view controller with relater classes (.h, .m).

But I don't know how to reuse such created view controller in different storyboard parts, depending on user context. I mean, I want to create this view controller just ones (not 3 times) and reuse it.

Should I look into using .xib files or something else?

Comment: Basically you are asking if you can create one view controller for "add / edit credit card" and a many to one relationship from other view controllers ? Two or more linking to that same page ?

Comment: If it's only that, go ahead and CTRL+Drag from a button for example from one view controller to the destination view controller and create a segue. Then test it. Then link from another view controller in the same way, through another button to the same destination view controller - your "add/edit credit card"

Comment: @BogdanLaukhin Please explain the question clearly. Not getting your question

Comment: added explanation in main question (it easier to read it there)